# Running PIP install with pythonw makes console scripts use pythonw instead of python

Tags: python, windows, pip, installation, pythonw

(windows 7 pro, python 2.7, PIP 9.0.1)

During the deployment process of our tools on client workstations, I use `pip` to install custom python libs. Because of the way it is packaged, I cannot have a `pip.exe`, so I run the `pip` module with `pythonw` to avoid the popping of a console.

```
$ c:\installdir\pythonw.exe -m pip install mylib --index http://pypi.intranet.org
```

`mylib` has a console entrypoint (let's call it `mylibutil`) defined in the `setup.py` file. So a `mylibutil.exe` is generated at install time which is fine.

But when I run it, nothing happens in my console. After parsing the content of the generated executable, I saw that the python used to run the script is `c:\installdir\pythonw.exe`, so not the correct one for a console script, but indeed the same one that was used when calling PIP.

Is there any workaround? Is this a win-specific bug of PIP?

I can use `python` instead of `pythonw` at install time, that would be alright, but I know the popping consoles can frighten some of the users sometimes.

> **NOTE**: I found [this trick](https://superuser.com/questions/140047/how-to-run-a-batch-file-without-launching-a-command-window) to wrap my python call through a no-console VBS script. So that's a workaround. However, I'd like it to keep things simpler if possible.

Comment: To keep things within Python, you can write a run_nocon.pyw script that uses `subprocess.call` to run a provided command line, with `creationflags` set to `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` (0x08000000), i.e. attach to a console host (conhost.exe) that doesn't create a window. This is even better than running pip via pythonw.exe, since any child process that an installation script creates will inherit the windowless console instead of creating a new console.

Comment: @eryksun, nice idea to not to depend on yet something else than python. I'll give it a try.